# simple jQuery effects don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found this code online on www.littlewebhut.com and there was a video and an explanation with it. I copy-pasted the code but the only thing is, is that it doesn't work on my computer. I have tried several computers at several different locations but it still doesn't work. What could I be doing wrong?
I saved the javascript code as my_code.js

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {})
  $("h1").click(function() {
  $("h2").hide(1000);
 });
});
```

```css
h2 {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Click Me</h1>
<h2>Heading two</h2>
<h3>Heading three</h3>
```

Comment: Do you have the jQuery library (jquery-1.8.0.min.js) saved as well?

Comment: Expanding on Patrick's comment, you likely just need to point to the CDN for jquery, enjoy

Comment: Thanks! What is the CDN and how do I point to it? I am sorry, this probably sounds very stupid.

Comment: Its look like conflict error or other error

Comment: I haven't done that Patrick. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Few typos in the first line of your code - 
`(function($) {})`.

- Typo1 - you have passed a wrong argument (`$`)
- Typo2 - you have closed the function too early

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("h1").click(function() {
    $("h2").hide(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
h2 {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Click Me</h1>
<h2>Heading two</h2>
<h3>Heading three</h3>
```

Comment: Looking forward for any explanation from downvoters.

Comment: Thank for answering! I edited them but it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Open the web console (Ctrl+Shift+K on Firefox) and see what it gives you..is it possible that you don't have jQuery.js ?

Comment: Do you mean the file in notepad?

Comment: @shunasammy You can mark my answer as the best one (:

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for helping! There was a typo in the jquery link.